# Angular 4 Materialize css sidenav not popping out

Tags: jquery, html, angular, materialize, navigationbar

I am using Materialize CSS for the make-up of my HTML in my angular 4 project.
I am using a side-nav that dissapears when the screen is to small and the menu-icon appears on top in my toolbar.

The problem now is that when I click the menu-button, the side-nav doesn't pop up.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div style="max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; margin: 0 auto">
    <nav class="toolbar">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <a href="http://www.leadingindicatorforecasting.com/" target="_blank"><img src="../../../../logo.png"></a>
            <label class="title-solv"> Solventure LIFe</label>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
                <li class="usericon"><i class="large material-icons">perm_identity</i></li>
                <li class="username">{{username}}</li>
                <li>
                    <i [routerLink]="['/login']" class="large material-icons">power_settings_newt</i>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div style="max-width:50px;">
        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed  own">
            <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid1 }"><a (click)="m1()" class="whitecolor">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid2 }"><a (click)="m2()" class="whitecolor">Dataset Management</a></li>
            <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid3 }"><a (click)="m3()" class="whitecolor">Forecast</a></li>
            <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid4 }"><a (click)="m4()" class="whitecolor">Reporting</a></li>
            <li [ngClass]="{'activated': isValid5}"><a (click)="m5()" class="whitecolor">Indicator Cloud</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
<div class="home">
    <div class="webbox">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I should add JQuery like in the examples, but wherever I place it, it doesn't work. How can I make the side-nav pop-out?

Comment: can you add a plunker for the same ?

Comment: @fangio are you using material.angular.io ?

Comment: @Rahul Singh I don't know how to use plunker but I only use this html, a component with little bit code and an index html with the scripts in as given on materialize css website

Comment: @Malik, materialize css, not material

Comment: @fangio are you importing materalize css in your angular cli.json file